# Highlight all text between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following example html, I would like to highlight all text between the two image tags (by adding a css background property). I have tried using jquerys .nextUntil() however this only uses the sibling nodes of the first element and so in this case it will not work.

Edit: The image tags below are intended to be invisible placeholders denoting the start and end points for a comment with the corresponding id within my text editor, everything in-between is the focus for the comment.

```
<div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor
        <img class="commentBoundaryStart data-commentid="1" src="img.png"/>
          sit amet,"
    </p>
    <p>
        consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    </p>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>
         Sed maximus laoreet augue
        <img class="commentBoundaryEnd" data-commentid="1" src="img2.png"/>
         , in ultrices sapien lobortis eu.
    </p>
    <p>
        Loremmmmm
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not straightforward as you will need to delve in to selection ranges and all kinds of nastiness. My suggestion would be to check out the excellent [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki) plugin to see what methods it has to help you.

Comment: To start with, you'll have to wrap the text elements in spans. Do you want to do that automatically or can you produce a better initial HTML ? Note that if he markup isn't more complex (just some p and some img, all in the same div), the solution will be simple.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yea i know, quite unfortunate. I have been using Rangy, I used it to dynamically insert the two images which I intended to be invisible markers for highlightable comments in a text editor I have.. but i cant see how it can help me with the highlighting as im not sure how to create a range without a selection

Comment: @dystroy Unfortunately I can't as i'm using textangular (https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) as my text editor and it dictates the hierarchy of the html, although I can have a play around and attempt to flatten it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking inspiration from the answers here I designed my own comprehensive script for handling this problem in an html block of infinite depth and complexity

```js
$(function () {
    var root = $('#textarea-0001');
    var cid = 1;
    
    var startMarker = $("img.commentBoundary[data-commentid='" + cid + "']").first();
    var endMarker = $("img.commentBoundary[data-commentid='" + cid + "']").last();

    // Wrap start points siblings with span
    startMarker.parent().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap("<span></span>");

    // Color its later siblings if they dont have the end point marker
    var has_done = false;
    startMarker.nextAll().andSelf().each(function() {
        if (has_done) {
            return;
        }
        if ($(this).has(endMarker).length > 0 || $(this).is(endMarker)) {
            has_done = true;
            return;
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(128, 204, 255, 0.5)");
        }
    });

    // Get parents up to root
    var parentsList = startMarker.parentsUntil(root);

    if (parentsList.has(endMarker).length === 0) {
        // go through each of these and access later siblings
        var has_returned = false;
        parentsList.each(function() {
            $(this).nextAll().each(function() {
                if (has_returned) {
                    return;
                }
                if ($(this).has(endMarker).length > 0) {
                    has_returned = true;
                    return;
                } else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.5)");
                }
            });    
        });
    };


    // find end point marker
    var endPointContainer = root.children().has(endMarker);

    // Wrap end points siblings in spans
    endMarker.parent().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap("<span></span>");

    // Color earlier siblings if they dont have start marker
    var is_done = false;
    $(endMarker.prevAll().andSelf().get().reverse()).each(function() {
        if (is_done) {
            return;
        }
        if ($(this).has(startMarker).length > 0 || $(this).is(startMarker)) {
            is_done = true;
            return;
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0, 122, 204, 0.5)");
        }
    });

    // Get parents up until end pointcontainer
    var parentsListEnd = endMarker.parentsUntil(endPointContainer);

    if (parentsListEnd.has(startMarker).length === 0) {
        // Go through each of these and access earlier siblings
        var is_returned = false;
        parentsListEnd.each(function() {
            $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
                if (is_returned) {
                    return;
                }
                if ($(this).has(startMarker).length > 0 || $(this).is(startMarker)) {

                    is_returned = true;
                    return;
                } else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0, 61, 102, 0.5)");
                }
            });

        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="textarea-0001">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor
                <img class="commentBoundary" data-commentid="1" src="img.png"/>
                  sit amet,
            </p>
            <p>
                <span> Hello! </span>
                <span>  consectetur adipiscing elit. </span>
                <h3>Header</h3>
            </p>
            <p>
                 consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            </p>
            <span>
                 consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            </span>
            <p>
                 Sed maximus laoreet augue
                <img class="commentBoundary" data-commentid="1" src="img2.png"/>
                 , in ultrices sapien lobortis eu.
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your specific markup (`img` in a `p`, with not greater depth), you can do this :

```js
// as you can't style text nodes, we first replace them
//  with span elements.
// This must be done only once and is independent of the
//  image markers
$('p').each(function(){
  var nodes = this.childNodes;
  for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType===3) {
      var text = nodes[i].textContent;
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
      this.replaceChild(span, nodes[i]);
    }
  }
});

// now, we colorize the first p
$('.commentBoundaryStart').nextUntil('.commentBoundaryEnd')
.css('color', 'red');

// the following ones
$('p:has(.commentBoundaryStart)')
.nextUntil(':has(.commentBoundaryEnd)').css('color', 'red');

// and the last one
$('p:has(.commentBoundaryEnd)').find('.commentBoundaryEnd')
.prevUntil('.commentBoundaryStart').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor"
        <img class="commentBoundaryStart" data-commentid="1" src="img.png"/>
        "  sit amet,"
    </p>
    <p>
        " consectetur adipiscing elit. "
    </p>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>
        " Sed maximus laoreet augue"
        <img class="commentBoundaryEnd" data-commentid="1" src="img2.png"/>
        " , in ultrices sapien lobortis eu."
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
```

You may have to adapt the code if your real HTML is more complex.

Of course it would be better to use `addClass` instead of `css`, which would allow for an easier cleaning when the images are moved or removed : just do `$('span').removeClass('betweenMarks')`.

Comment: Appreciate the response and by the specification I have provided it fits the bill so take my vote, however I don't want to persist this highlighting, it was intended to be used when the user selected a 'view comments' option - and so adding and removing these span tags each time has the potential to cause some formatting errors or busyness within my html that is not wanted. However if i don't find a better solution this one may be useful

Comment: @alsco77 You have to add the spans only once. It's better to keep it : you do it at page loading and you do the other operations when your images are moved.

Comment: this answer assumes that all my parent elements are <p>s, for an example with headers this will not work.. i have updated my html to match

Comment: @alsco77 As I said, you'll have to tune it for your HTML. I've done a simple change for that header but it looks like I'm not answering a question anymore but doing your work

Comment: Yes i do apologise for the shortsightedness of my question and very much appreciate your response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

possible solution 1 for this case.

It works for only 1 `<p>` between images. You need to change it a bit if you have more than 1 `<p>` with nextAll and some `if` with `indexOf img` or something like that.

```js
$(function() {

//coment start line
$('img.commentBoundaryStart').parent().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<span></span>');
$('img.commentBoundaryStart').next().css("background","red");

//middle lines
var has_returned = false;
$('img.commentBoundaryStart').parent().nextAll().each(function() {
    if (has_returned) { return; }
    if ($(this).contents().hasClass("commentBoundaryEnd")) {
        has_returned = true;
        return;
    } else {
        $(this).css("background","red");
    }
}); 

//end line
$('img.commentBoundaryEnd').parent().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<span></span>');
$('img.commentBoundaryEnd').prev().css("background","red");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor"
    <img class="commentBoundaryStart" data-commentid="1" src="img.png"/>
    "  sit amet,"
</p>
<p>
    " consectetur adipiscing elit. "
</p>
<p>
    " consectetur adipiscing elit. "
</p>
<span>
    " consectetur adipiscing elit. "
</span>
<p>
    " Sed maximus laoreet augue"
    <img class="commentBoundaryEnd" data-commentid="1" src="img2.png"/>
    " , in ultrices sapien lobortis eu."
</p>
<p>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case you can delete both `end()`

Comment: that's what I meant, they're useless

Comment: Thanks however I don't believe this solution will work as there can be an arbitrary number of different elements in between my pictures and the middle <p> tag was just inserted as the most basic case.

Comment: @nada yea looking good however what if there are more paragraphs after the commentBoundaryEnd? In my test it also gets highlighted

Comment: @alsco77 i chenged it again just after the comment. now after `commentBoundaryEnd` not highlights anymore